Initializing map of polymorphic function pointers
I'm doing a personal project which boils down to a task management command line tool. The idea is to take some of the concepts I've been using in higher level languages and apply them to C++, as well as get used to the SQLite C/C++ API. But I digress.
The idea of the implementation is to use a static SchemaBuilder.build() method, which takes in a vector of strings and parses it accordingly. Since we can't use switch statements with string literals in C++, I defaulted to the strategy previously used for the command parser, which was using a std::map<std::string, function_pointer>.
I'm having a bit of a hard time getting it to compile. Here's the code:
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class TableSchema{
};

class TaskSchema : public TableSchema{
};

class ProjectSchema : public TableSchema{
};

typedef TableSchema* (*BuildFunction)(std::vector<std::string> args);

class SchemaBuilder{
public:
    static TableSchema* build(std::vector<std::string> args); 
};

TaskSchema* buildTask(std::vector<std::string>);
ProjectSchema* buildProject(std::vector<std::string>);

std::map<std::string, BuildFunction> buildMap = {
    { "task", buildTask },
    { "project", buildProject }
};

//weirdest part is that this one compiles while the above one doesn't
void tmp(){
    std::map<std::string, BuildFunction> tmp;
    tmp["task"] = buildTask;
    tmp["project"] = buildProject;
}

TaskSchema* buildTask(std::vector<std::string> params){
    return nullptr; 
}

ProjectSchema* buildProject(std::vector<std::string> params){
    return new ProjectSchema(params[0], params[1]);
}

Error messages:
src/schema-builder.cpp:6:1: error: could not convert ‘{{"task", buildTask}, {"project", buildProject}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, TableSchema* (*)(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >)>’
    6 | };
      | ^
      | |
      | <brace-enclosed initializer list>

The tmp function isn't part of the project, just a test to see if what I'm doing is compilable - it is.
Needless to say, ProjectSchema and TaskSchema both publicly inherit from TableSchema.

Please include error messages in the question, and read about the [mcve].

buildTask and buildProject have different types, so it's impossible to assign a type to the initializer list. It does not try to find implicit conversions to a common type.

Side note : This is C++ never use naked new/delete like this and ever return "owning raw pointers",  you build task should return a std::unique_ptr<ProjectSchema> and use std::make_unique<ProjectSchema>. Whoever taught you C++ didn't get the C++11 memo I think ;)

@molbdnilo how is that a thing in a language that supports class inheritance? also, wouldn't take make it so the tmp() function generated the same error? I tried a similar pattern in a watered down test project, using a vector, and it worked fine. The problem seems to be the map - and I'm quite sure there's a way to work around, since this is an extremely common pattern

@PepijnKramer definitely. I intent to move to smart pointers once I get the base functionality going. Thanks for the pointer though!

You can also do std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr = std::make_unique<Derived> if you so wish

@Pedro haha std::unique_pts should be your base functionality. Raw pointers and when to use them (as non-owning they are fine) is the advanced case nowadays :)

@PepijnKramer right. but does that fix my issue with the whole function pointer to derived class situation? i feel adding an extra layer of indirection (with generics, for that matter) might add complexity to the problem

Not sure I didn't really review all the details of your code. And note template classes are not generics (as in .Net generics)... they are fully evaluated at compile time and the runtime overhead is minimal.  For function pointers in C++ you could use std::function<void (Base*)> though that comes with a little runtime overhead. But sure in C++ you can still use function pointers and use Base* as a (non-owning) pointer. You will have to give your base and derived classes virtual destructors though

well, it is a whole can of worms indeed - hence the decision to leave it for further down the line after I get the app up and running. made the migration, still getting the same error.

@PepijnKramer managed to fix it using virtual and override keywords. and yes, whoever taught me C++ taught me "C with classes" instead. I'm slowly getting up to speed with the state of the art. this project is the first step in that direction. Thanks for the pointers mate, apologies for any lack of manners - compiler problems often get frustrating heh. Cheers!

@PedroBarbeira Hey no problem, I even added a bit of an example for you. Just treat C++ as a completely new language and you will do fine :)

Got it working
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class TableSchema{
  //polymorphic behaviour through virtual methods
};

class TaskSchema : public TableSchema{
  //polymorphic behaviour through [type] [method_name]([params][]) override
};

class ProjectSchema : public TableSchema{
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<TableSchema> (*BuildFunction)(std::vector<std::string> args);

class SchemaBuilder{
public:
    static TableSchema* build(std::vector<std::string> args); 
};

std::unique_ptr<TableSchema> buildTask(std::vector<std::string>);
std::unique_ptr<TableSchema> buildProject(std::vector<std::string>);

std::map<std::string, BuildFunction> buildMap = {
    { "task", buildTask },
    { "project", buildProject }
};

std::unique_ptr<TableSchema> buildTask(std::vector<std::string> params){
    return nullptr; 
}

std::unique_ptr<TableSchema> buildProject(std::vector<std::string> params){
    return new ProjectSchema(params[0], params[1]);
}

Whoever you are remember this the next time you ask a question and end up solving your own problem. Sometimes answering yourself is helping the world

Here is a sketch of what I mean :)
Also see
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <string_view>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class TableSchema
{
public:
    virtual ~TableSchema() = default; // you will need a virtual destructor
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;   // and some polymorphic methods
                                      // you can use through pointers to this baseclass
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class TaskSchema :
    public TableSchema
{
public:
    explicit TaskSchema(const std::vector<std::string>& args) :
        m_args{ args } // copy arguments
    {
    }
    
    ~TaskSchema() override = default;

    void DoSomething() override
    {
        std::cout << "Task : " << m_args[0] << ", " << m_args[1] << "\n"; // small demo, ofcourse totally unsafe (assumes 2 entries in vector)
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::string> m_args;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class ProjectSchema :
    public TableSchema
{
public:
    explicit ProjectSchema(const std::vector<std::string>& args) :
        m_args{ args } // copy arguments
    {
    }

    ~ProjectSchema() override = default;

    void DoSomething() override
    {
        std::cout << "Project : " << m_args[0] << ", " << m_args[1] << "\n"; // small demo, ofcourse totally unsafe (assumes 2 entries in vector)
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::string> m_args;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// put all administration for creation of functions
// in a factory class 

class Factory
{
public:
    // Your creat function
    static std::unique_ptr<TableSchema> Create(const std::string_view type, const std::vector<std::string>& args)
    {
        if (m_map.find(type) == m_map.end())
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument{ "unsupported type" };
        }

        // you can get a function out of the map
        auto create_function = m_map.at(type);

        // and then call it.
        return create_function(args);
    };

private:
    // In C++ use 'using' instead of typedef it plays nicer with templates
    // when you use std::function you can also use lambda expressions (with captures) as functions
    using create_function_t = std::function<std::unique_ptr<TableSchema>(const std::vector<std::string>&)>;

    // Create a map of creation functions
    // each function is a lambda expression
    static inline std::unordered_map<std::string_view, create_function_t> m_map
    { {
        {"task", [](const std::vector<std::string>& args) { return std::make_unique<TaskSchema>(args); }},
        {"project", [](const std::vector<std::string>& args) { return std::make_unique<ProjectSchema>(args); }}
    } };
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Now you can use it like this

int main()
{
    auto task_ptr = Factory::Create("task", { "arg1","arg2" });
    auto project_ptr = Factory::Create("project", { "arg3","arg4" });

    task_ptr->DoSomething();
    project_ptr->DoSomething();
}


Amazing! Thank you so much :) The lambda syntax is definitely a game changer for me!

Nitpick: m_map.find() returns an iterator to the found item. m_map.at() performs the same lookup that map::find() does. So you are searching m_map twice unnecessarily. You should get rid of m_map.at() and use the iterator to access the function, eg: auto found = m_map.find(type); if (found == m_map.end()) { ... } auto create_function = found->second; ...

@RemyLebeau You are right. I just chose this syntax for slightly better readability for now (to avoid the auto create_function = (*it)->second; syntax). In fact I'd probably take a different approach where my arguments would be template packs (but that too would have been too far from OP's question and C++ experience level)
